# Remove an old Kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, upgrade, kernel

My network adapter wasn't supported when I initially installed Ubuntu server 20.04. This was several years ago, and my memory of how I addressed the issue is pretty foggy; I'm fairly certain that I looked-up the first version of the linux kernel which had a driver for my network adapter and followed some guides to install / use that one. I'm pretty sure that was version 5.17.

Fast forward to today. I did a release upgrade to 22.04, and found an article saying that the kernel in 22.04 was using version 6.0+, which should still have driver support for my adapter. However, when I typed uname -r after the release upgrade and restart I'm still on 5.17. I found an article online saying that manual kernel installs wont update with apt upgrade, and presumably also with release upgrades. I checked before the release upgrade and I was using 5.17 with 20.04 as well. I can't seem to find any information about undoing that manual kernel install I did like 5 years ago.

I'd like to use the latest kernel with 22.04, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: what linux kernel version was compatible with you adapter.?

Comment: I mentioned in the question that my memory is foggy, but  because the kernel was 5.17 prior to runing the upgrade, I'm fairly certain it was 5.17